# Impact of modifying value of batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb in cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have a question regarding batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb, a property cassandra.yaml. My current setup has batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50.

I have seen DataStax 6 documentation, it shows 640 kb as default.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configCassandra_yaml.html

So is it fine to change batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb property? What all is can get impacted by it?

Answer (score 4):

I would not change that setting without a *very* good reason.  The value of `batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb` exists to protect the coordinator node from crashing, in the event that an extremely large batch is sent.  Batch statements utilized in a RDBMS fashion (sending thousands of batched writes to the same table) are known to be problematic, and this setting helps to protect against them.

I have had application teams approach me about increasing this value (when using batches correctly), because their payload columns exceed this threshold.  I take those on a case-by-case basis.

I cannot speak to how DataStax decided on their (much higher) default.  My guess, is that it might have something to do with their Solr or Graph integrations.

**tl;dr;**

`batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb` is one setting where the default should almost never need to be adjusted.

Comment: I have to update two tables atomically. I have two tables one is student_by_name and the other student_by_subject. The single statement is more than 50 kb size. What should be the best approach?

Comment: @PurushottamBaghel Ok, it sounds like you're trying to use `BATCH` the right way, so that's good. Try to compute the max limit that your batch will ever hit, and set it to that plus a little extra (just to be safe).  So if your max will be 75kb, maybe set it to 100kb.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, I will do that same. But do I need to change any other properties too, so nothing should break??

Comment: @PurushottamBaghel Maybe also check and adjust the `batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb` so that your logs don't fill-up. But that should do it.

Comment: I will increase batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb to 100 and batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb to 10. By chance is there any way to test that everything is working fine?